# Return a valid iframe HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a block of code that detects youtube links from an HTML component. The function works and it returns an iframe, but the problem is that the iframe returned is within a quote "", which i think cancelled rendering of the iframe on the page. Here's the code:

```
    Template.statusBox.helpers({
  statuses: function(){
    return Status.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  },
  formattedDate: function(){
    var timecreated = this.createdAt;
    return moment(timecreated).fromNow();
  },
  author: function(){
    return this.author;
  },
  youtube: function(){
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName('hz-status-content');
    var innerContent = content[0].innerHTML;

    //regex to identify Youtube link in status
    const parts = (/(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/([\w\=\?]+)/gm).exec(innerContent)
    let mediaContent = ''

    if (parts && parts[3]) {
      let id = parts[3]

      if (id.indexOf('v=') > -1) {
        const subParts = (/v=([\w]+)+/g).exec(id)

        if (subParts && subParts[1]) {
          id = subParts[1]
        }
      }

      mediaContent = `http://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`
    }
    var hzYoutube =  '<iframe src="'+ mediaContent +'" type="text/html" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
    return hzYoutube;

  }
});
```

... and I call the helpers in my HTML code like this:

```
<template name="statusBox">
  {{#each statuses}}
  <div class="hz-newsfeed small-12 columns">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
      <img src="/hand.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="hz-newsfeed-name small-10 columns">
      {{author}} <span class="hz-greyfont">posted a status</span><br/>
      <span class="hz-greyfont-smaller"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{formattedDate}}</span>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <p class="hz-status-content">{{{status}}}</p>
        {{#with FS.GetFile "images" images}}
          <div class="row text-center">
            <a href="{{this.url}}" data-lightbox="newsfeedimages" class="thumbnail">
              <img src="{{this.url store='thumb'}}" />
            </a>
          </div>
        {{/with}}
        {{youtube}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row comment-section">
        {{> commentsBox id=this._id}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

...and this returns something like this:
[image: error in iframe codeblock]

and this is how it looks on the browser:
[image: iframe didnt render correctly]

Can you point me to the right direction, please?

**EDITED:** I have edited the previous code to provide the full code as per requested. This is part of MeteorJs project, and I am using Blaze.

Comment: You aren't showing how you use this function. Provide a **runnable** [mcve]. Also post actual code not images of code

Comment: The problem is most likely in the part where you execute the function, not the function itself. Can you show us the code?

Comment: @charlietfl Can't provide a runnable example as this is part of a meteorjs project. I've edited the question above to provide a full code.

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven I've edited the question with the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for your trouble @charlietfl & @ThomasvanBroekhoven.

This is the solution I found:
Use triple-curly braced handlebars {{{youtube}}} in steady of just double {{youtube}} to return the raw HTML to page.

source: http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html

Comment: No problem, glad you found it!